# Neural net with scalar Boolean output for binary classification

Tags: neural-networks

How can I create and train a neural network with a scalar Boolean output for binary classification, and hopefully have it automatically compute the `"ErrorRate"` property (described [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrainingProgressMeasurements.html)) during training?

Here is an attempt that resulted in errors:

```
(* create training data *)

rmf = RegionMember[Disk[]];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}];
data = Thread[pts -> rmf[pts]];

(* construct net *)

net = NetChain[{100, Ramp, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> NetDecoder["Boolean"]]

(* attempt training *)

NetTrain[net, data]
```

This results in:

> First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element.
>
> NetTrain::encgenfail1: Could not encode input number 459 for port
>   "Output": input was not a sequence of length 1. Please check the
>   example.

I am not experienced with neutral networks. I am generally confused about how to specify that the output of a net is even a scalar (not a vector). In the example above, this does not seem to be the problem as changing the training data to use size-1 Boolean vectors instead of Boolean scalars does not fix the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach a `SequenceLastLayer` to your chain to get this to work:

```
net = NetChain[{100, Ramp, 1, SequenceLastLayer[]}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> NetDecoder["Boolean"]]
```

Normally, to get a network to output a scalar, you can do `"Output"->"Scalar"`, but since you're already using a `NetDecoder`, this doesn't work easily. A `SequenceLastLayer` always returns a scalar, so this is an easy way to work around this issue.

It does seem to me that the boolean NetDecoder could handle this a little better. You can set the `"InputDepth"` of the NetDecoder like so: `NetDecoder[{"Boolean", "InputDepth"->2}]`, but you should also be able to specify that the input should be a scalar here.

Comment: +1. Similar trick is `PartLayer[1]`.